# Google Forms - Inserting an image in a multiple choice field using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, multiple-choice, google-form-quiz

I have created a script which will add images to a Google form to produce a multiple choice quiz.

At the moment it adds an image *then* adds the options (A,B,C,D). The image and the option are two separate items. As a result, I can't randomise the order as I need to make sure the image and question remain together.

Manually creating the quiz allows for an option to add the image *with* the question so it appears as one item.  This would be preferable as it would allow me to randomise the question order.

I've had a look at the Forms Service API, but I can't see an option to add an image to a multiple choice question.  Is there a possible solution to this (other than doing it by hand?)

Found this question with a very similar issue, but with no reply:
[Google Script: Add an image to a Google Form item (different from ImageItem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45212222/google-script-add-an-image-to-a-google-form-item-different-from-imageitem)

Comment: AFAIK, you can use [**`createChoice(value)`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#createchoicevalue) but you can only add text. Manually (using the Google Form UI) you can add image for multiple choice but in the Apps Script you can only add text. After some digging, I've found a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765518) for this, you can follow this ticket to be updated. Hope this helps.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Thank you!