# Insert image in multiplechoiceitem in Google Forms with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I need to insert a Google Drive image in each choice of the multiple choice item. Upon checking the documentation, the Class `.addMultipleChoiceItem()` doesn't support the method `.setImage()`. Is there another way to insert an image from Google Drive?.

Example:

```
var form = FormApp.openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
var item = form.addListItem();
item.setTitle('Do you prefer cats or dogs?')
.setChoices([
    item.createChoice('Cats'), <------ I need to insert an imagen of a cat 
in this choice with code.
    item.createChoice('Dogs')
]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Based from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022122/google-forms-inserting-an-image-in-a-multiple-choice-field-using-apps-script), you can add image for multiple choice using the Google Form UI. But in the Apps Script, you can only add text. This is also filed as a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765518).